# Insert to Mysql With PHP&Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I used this example : http://woork.blogspot.com/2007/10/insert-record-into-database-using-ajax.html

it is working when using with Numbers for example if i enter number in these textbox it is work but when i enter string i get this error: "Unknown column 'text' in 'field list'"

'text' is text that write in the textbox instead of 'text' i write '123' it is working

Could you please suggest me way urgent.

Thanks all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that in your table there is no column named `text`. To fix this, either rename the field you wish to update/insert to text, or figure out which column you really wish to update/insert the text into.

Since your field is going to be updating/inserting a string, you need to also make sure you wrap the string in quotes.

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`val1`,`val2`) VALUES('".$val1."','".$val2."')
```

Comment: sorry i updated question. it is actuall not column name ,'text ' is word that i write in the textbox

Comment: I updated my post. You need to wrap the variable in quotes since it's a string.

Comment: You need to wrap the variable in quotes in your query.

Comment: i use this
$pid= $_GET['pid'];
$uid= $_GET['uid'];
$comment= $_GET['comment'];

$insertSite_sql = 'INSERT INTO comment (comment,post_ID,user_ID) 
VALUES('. $comment. ','. $pid. ','. $uid. ')';
$insertSite= mysql_query($insertSite_sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Yea there are no quotes there. Do: `$sql = "INSERT INTO comment (comment, psot_ID, user_ID) VALUES('".$comment."','".$pid."','".$uid."')";`

Comment: @MarcusRecck how can i wrap? i don't have idea about it? Also i get differen error messaje, For example when i enter 'ajax' in the textbox it give differen message me. I think my query is not safety, you can give advise plz

Comment: I updated my comment to reflect what you insert statement should be. I just changed the variable though from `$insertSite_sql` to `$sql`

Comment: Thank yo @MarcusRecck , it is working after using " quotes, thanks, And i wanna ask there will be sql injection or other security problem,  I am new in PHP

Comment: From your code, yes there are many ways to inject it. Since you're mysql, look to the manual about `mysql_real_escape_string`. Otherwise you could try learning PDO and binding params.

Comment: ok, one more question after adding to mysql , how can write that comment on page?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_ID = 123 ORDER BY id ASC` execute that with `mysql_query` but change 123 to whatever post_ID you want. Then use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to loop through the comments on that post.

Comment: how can i use this , insert query is in different page: insert.php this page have insert query and i have other page :comment.php that show comments. insert  and select queries were in the same page i could make this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your column has a text or varchar datatype. Theoretically it should throw a different error if that was the case. But the fact that you're able to insert numbers and not text makes me think you've got some sort of INT datatype.

Obviously most importantly make sure your hello table really exists.